# ajax chat application with php and jquery issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chat

I want to write an application for chat with php in one of my project. I have read an article about chat in csstricks. In that article's author mentioned that we should update the chat area and this is ok for me, buy my question is that if I update the chat room with jquery timer in some seconds it won't make pressure for the server? especially when number of users is more than 1000 and for each user we send an ajax request every 2 second to the server. 
thank you for your help.

Comment: You should look for more modern solutions, especially websockets. Not only is your solution heavy but users won't like a 2 seconds delay, as it means some messages came between the one they're answering and their own one.

Comment: I have design another app with node js with push and pull. But I want some thing in php and this method is confusing me. @DenysSéguret

Comment: You should look at the implementation of existing PHP websocket chats. You don't need node to do websockets.

Comment: Ok buddy :) I will take a look at your solution in the net @DenysSéguret

Comment: PHP+websockets isn't *my* solution (look at my profile) ;)

Comment: @DenysSéguret Oh I found some thing in your profile called Miaou :) thank you buddy